# How to send AJAX request without encoding url

Tags: jquery, salesforce, soql, urldecode

I am trying to get data from salesforce API using SOQL method. Problem is that when send ajax get request it encodes url that results in failure of $ajax request.

How can I send plain url in ajax request without encoding url.

Sample request is HERE:

```
                     $.ajax({
                             type: "GET",
                             url: "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/query?q=SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email= '" + Email + "'",
                             headers: {
                                 "Authorization": "OAuth " + access_token,
                                 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                             },
                             crossDomain: true,
                             dataType: 'application/json',
                             success: function (responseData) {
                                 console.log(responseData);
                             },
                             error: function (request, status, error) {
                                 console.log(request.responseText);
                             }
                         });
```

Comment: What is the actual error that is occurring?

Comment: @JasonP here is the error - http://screencast.com/t/XwwVp2EK it returns undefined response

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `q=SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email= '" + Email` works fine in postman it reutrns response data. But when i try it in my script it returns undefined - Here you see  [screencast.com/t/XwwVp2EK]

Comment: try to replace the spaces with "+"

Comment: @YoshiakiNakamura Now that i have replaced the spaces with + its good the only thing that is creating error is that `'` is converted into %22

i.e. https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email=%someemail@yahoo.com%22

Comment: @FaisalIjaz try %27 for  '

Comment: @YoshiakiNakamura I did but no result

Comment: @FaisalIjaz did you tried to remove it ?  `/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email=someemail@yahoo.com`

Comment: @YoshiakiNakamura

NO. URL is here. https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/query?q=SELEC‌​T+Id+FROM+Contact+WH‌​ERE+Email=%27sabirre‌​hman78@yahoo.com%27

Comment: @FaisalIjaz what about encoding Email=  to  Email%3D

Comment: @YoshiakiNakamura 

Encoding characters will not work. All I want is plain text url without special chars so that SOQL can can be executed.

Comment: @FaisalIjaz did you tried  \' instead of ' ?

Comment: @YoshiakiNakamura 

Yea it did not work.